# How to specify dtype for pd.read_csv when there are no column headers?

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently writing code to analyse a large subset of data. I have used the pandas to read the text files and I am printing it using data.head(). I need to specify the dtype for 9 columns (the ninth one being null) because the process would be too memory intensive otherwise but I have no clue how to specify the dtype for columns lacking column headers. Would it be the same as for specifying dtype for column headers? For reference my columns data type would probably be the follows:

Column 1: Mixed as it contains alphanumeric characters

Column 2: Date in the format YY/MM/DD

Column 3: Time in Hours/Minutes/Seconds/Milliseconds

Column 4: Str

Column 5: Time

Column 6: Str

Column 7: Time

Column 8: Time

Column 9: Null

[Here is an excerpt of the text file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfyyX.png)

Here is also an excerpt of my code

```
    import sys
    import os
    import glob
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np

    path = '/Users/MysteriousHo-Oh1231/Downloads/Datapoints1/*.txt'
    dataframes = []
    for filename in glob.iglob(path):
      data = pd.read_csv(filename, header=None, delimiter='\t',  dtype={0: object, 1: int, 2: int, 3: object, 4: int, 5: object, 6: int, 7: int, 8: None})
      print(data.head())
```

I tried the above code and it returned this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLti6.png):

Please help me with this!

Comment: python starts at 0, not 1

Comment: first remove `try/except` to see error messages because you have mistakes. ie. it has to be `dtype=` without `s`, There is no variable `datetime64` but `np.datetime64` but usually you have to use `data[2] = pd.to_datetime(data[2])` after loading data.

Comment: BTW: you have to use `print( data.head() )`

Comment: @furas Yeah I forgot to write that haha! I'll do that. Thanks for catching that! Thanks for everything else as well!

Comment: BTW: you could add data as text and then we could use it to test ideas/code.

Comment: @furas Thanks for everything. I have removed the try except blocks like you said and have recieved 2 errors like you said would be present. How should I go about resolving the code?

Answer (score 1):

Define 3 following conversion functions:

```
def strToDate(tt):
    return pd.to_datetime(tt, yearfirst=True)

def strToTime(tt):
    return pd.to_datetime(tt, format='%I:%M:%S.%f').time()

def strToTime2(tt):
    return pd.Timestamp(float(tt), unit='s').time()
```

Then read your DataFrame, passing them as converters for the columns
requiring "specialized" conversion:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', header=None, converters={ 1: strToDate,
    2: strToTime, 4: strToTime2, 6: strToTime2, 7: strToTime2 })
```

When you print `df.info()`, then:

- column *1* (date) is of *datetime64[ns]* type,
- column *8* (*NaN*s) is of *float64* type,
- all other columns are of *object* type.

But don't be misguided. In *Pandas* the type of *object* means actually
"something other than a number or datetime".

When you retrieve **individual** values, e.g. `df.iloc[0,2]` you
will get: `datetime.time(11, 24, 31, 758000)`, similar for any cell
from column *4*, *6* or *7*, so they are of just the required type.

## Another solution based on *Timedelta*

Define converter functions as:

```
def strToDate(tt):
    return pd.to_datetime(tt, yearfirst=True)

def strToTimeDelta(tt):
    return pd.Timedelta(float(tt), unit='S')
```

Read your dataframe:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Input.csv', header=None, converters={ 1: strToDate,
    2: pd.Timedelta, 4: strToTimeDelta, 6: strToTimeDelta, 7: strToTimeDelta })
```

(to convert column *2* use native *pandasonic* function *pd.Timedelta*).

Then, if you need to convert some *Timedelta* column (e.g. column *7*)
to the total number of seconds, including the fractional part, run:

```
df[7].dt.seconds + df[7].dt.microseconds / 1e6
```

But the default result of reading columns *4*, *6* and *7* is just
**float** i.e. the number of seconds.

They are **conceptually** times, but actually:

- in the input file they are kept as **text**,
- after *read_csv* they are **floats** keeping the number of seconds.

So why do you need any conversion of these columns?

Comment: Hey there. So for the rest of the columns, I should use the object data type rather than any special conversion method or should I leave it alone? Because right now my terminal is returning 1 column using the df.info command even though there are 9 columns. I also wanted to add that I am using a for loop to add all the text files for me automatically rather than just using a specific file. Although the text files have the same format, it won't affect anything right? Thanks for everything else!

Comment: Also, if I wanted to use numpy or scipy to find the mean of the values, would that affect anything?

Comment: Mean value can be computed for **numeric** columns. If you want something like *mean* for "time-like" columns, then probably you should convert the time value to e.g. the number ot seconds and then compute the mean (for each column of interest).

Comment: I tried using the `to_numeric` function to convert it into a number value but it isn't working

Comment: To convert a *datetime.time* object (*tt*) to the number of seconds you can use
such formula as *n = tt.hour * 3600 + tt.minute * 60 * tt.second + tt.microsecond / 1e6*.
Other option is to convert my solution to keep the columns of interest
as *Timedelta* and to get the number of seconds use its *seconds* attribute.